# IPhone: GLKTextureInfo not working using Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, grand-central-dispatch, glkit

I am developing an IPhone OpengGL app using the GLKit, and using the following code to create textures:

```
NSRange dotRange = [textureFileName rangeOfString:@"." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (dotRange.location == NSNotFound){
            NSLog(@"OpenGLDRawMaterial:createTextureFromFileName, incorrect file name given in inputs");
            return nil;
        }   

   GLKTextureInfo *newTexture;

        NSError *error = nil;   // stores the error message if we mess up
        NSString *bundlepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[textureFileName substringToIndex:dotRange.location] 
                                                               ofType:[textureFileName substringFromIndex:(dotRange.location+1)]];

newTexture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:bundlepath options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft] error:&error];
```

The code works very well , as long as it works in a main thread. Every single time i attempt to make it work in a worker thread i am getting the following message:

"2013-03-04 02:09:01.528 Puppeteer[7063:1503] Error loading texture from image: Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=17 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 17.)" UserInfo=0x1c5977e0 "

The code i am using for the grand central dispatch queue is :

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadPlayViewBackgroundTexture", 0);

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
       [self createTexturesForPlayView]; // method calling texture creation

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  });
             });
             dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

If you have any insights or ideas how to fix this issue and have textures being loaded in background i would be very grateful :)
Cheers,
Stéphane

Comment: You can't simultaneously access the same OpenGL ES context from multiple threads, so are you properly locking to make sure no rendering operations, etc. are happening at the same time as your texture upload? Also, you will need to assign your OpenGL ES context to the thread of your GCD block using `-setCurrentContext:` or there may be no valid OpenGL ES context when trying to upload your texture.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the documentation for `+textureWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` includes this statement:check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

`This class method loads the texture into the sharegroup attached to the current context for the thread this method is called on.`

When you call `-textureWithContentsOfFile:` from a background thread, that thread has no OpenGL context set (the current GL context is per-thread state), and so GLKit doesn't know which sharegroup to load the texture into.

But, you're making this harder than it needs to be.  GLKit can already manage asynchronous texture loading itself.  Look at the variant `-textureWithContentsOfFile:options:queue:completionHandler:`.  You don't have to create your own queue at all: you can simply pass in the main queue to receive notification when the load is complete.